# Move script if upload is completed

Tags: upload, ftp, move

I have a script which has to move uploaded files from the first directory to the second directory.
The problem is that the script already moves the files during upload.
Anyone who can help?

```
#!/bin/sh

lockfile=/home/mediaze111/cronjobs/zenon_move.lock

if ( set -o noclobber; echo "$$" > "$lockfile") 2> /dev/null; then
    trap 'rm -f "$lockfile"; exit $?' INT TERM EXIT
    if [ "$(ls -A /home/mediaze111/domains/optimaal.fm/ZenonImport/Import1/)" ]; then
            ps faux | grep -E 'UPLOAD' | grep -v 'grep' > /dev/null || mv -f /home/mediaze111/domains/optimaal.fm/ZenonImport/Import1/*.* /home/mediaze111/domains/optimaal.fm/ZenonImport/Import2/
    fi

    rm -f "$lockfile"
    trap - INT TERM EXIT
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

u can get the file size before upload . then check the destination file size . if same move uploaded. pul all the script in a loop so when was the same break it an move files.